# Use a column as a selection Argument in SQLite and Android

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I use a column as part of my query.

I have done this using a raw SQLite command in SQliteStudio.

```
select _id, docholder, notes, docnumber, validto, doctype from documentslist where replaced <> 1 and validto < (((strftime('%s', 'now')*1000)) + (86400000 * warningin))
```

But below one in Android Studio is not working.

```
    private void showList(){
    mDbHelper = new DocumentsDbHelper(this);
    db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] projection = {
            DocumentEntry._ID,
            DocumentEntry.COLUMN_DOC_HOLDER,
            DocumentEntry.COLUMN_NOTES,
            DocumentEntry.COLUMN_DOC_NUMBER,
            DocumentEntry.COLUMN_VALID_TO,
            DocumentEntry.COLUMN_DOC_TYPE
    };


    String selection = DocumentEntry.COLUMN_EXPIRED + " <> ? AND " + DocumentEntry.COLUMN_VALID_TO + " < ";
    String[] selectionArg = {"1", String.valueOf(((System.currentTimeMillis()) + (86400000 * Integer.parseInt(DocumentEntry.COLUMN_WARN_IN))))};

    String setOrder = DocumentEntry.COLUMN_VALID_TO + " ASC";

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            DocumentEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArg,
            null,
            null,
            setOrder
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue may well be that you may be trying to convert a string to an integer where you have specified `Integer.parseInt(DocumentEntry.COLUMN_WARN_IN)` (*that is unless DocumentEntry.COLUMN_WARN_IN resolves to an integer, it would appear that it may resolve to warningin*)

Additionally you've omitted the inclusion of the 2nd parameter, so that cannot be included and may result in a paremeter mismatch issue as you've provided two but only asked for one to be used.

I'd suggest using:-

```
String selection = DocumentEntry.COLUMN_EXPIRED + " <> ? AND " + DocumentEntry.COLUMN_VALID_TO + " <  (((strftime('%s', 'now')*1000)) + (86400000 * warningin))";
String[] selectionArg = {"1"};
```

or perhaps more correctly, assuming that `DocumentEntry.COLUMN_WARN_IN` resolves to **warningin**, using :-

```
String selection = DocumentEntry.COLUMN_EXPIRED + 
    " <> ? AND " + 
    DocumentEntry.COLUMN_VALID_TO + 
    " <  (((strftime('%s', 'now')*1000)) + (86400000 * " +
    DocumentEntry.COLUMN_WARN_IN + 
    "))";
String[] selectionArg = {"1"};
```

- **Note** *this is in principle code and has not been tested, so there may be the typing errors*.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. I have also realized that I missed the "?" for the second selection DocumentEntry.COLUMN_VALID_TO + " < ".